# table cell width issue

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 rows where i need varying cell width as

```
<body bgcolor="#14B3D9">
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">25</td>
        <td width="50%">50</td>
        <td width="25%">25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">50</td>
        <td width="30%">30</td>
        <td width="20%">20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I cannot get the width as specified the second row also gets the width of the first row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html table cell width for different rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows)

Answer (score 21):

to do this with one table you need to introduce more columns and then get the column widths by using `colspan` so you can get the combined widths you require

to get this to work well across browser you will possibly need to use the `<col> and <colgroup>` elements : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4

```
<body bgcolor="#14B3D9">
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<colgroup>
<col width="25%">
<col width="25%">
<col width="25%">
<col width="5%">
<col width="20%">
</colgroup>

    <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td colspan="2">50</td>
        <td colspan="2">25</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">50</td>
        <td colspan="2">30</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: As mentioned by Till in the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows I think this is against the initial idea of tables.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can just have each *tr* set to *display:block*, and it will allow you to set different column widths for each row.

Comment: instead of _display:block_ you can try `<tr style="display: inline-table; width: 100%;">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth:child

However it will apply to all rows. This will be relative and not absolute.

```
    tr>:nth-child(6){ 
    width: 20%;
    }
    tr>:nth-child(7){ 
    width: 80%;
    }
```