# html table cell width for different rows

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [table cell width issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937774/table-cell-width-issue)

I have a table set up as

```
<html>
 <body bgcolor="#14B3D9">
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">25</td>
        <td width="50%">50</td>
        <td width="25%">25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">50</td>
        <td width="30%">30</td>
        <td width="20%">20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i get the 2 rows to have different cell width?

Comment: rowspan if you want 1 row to be 2 rows width.

Comment: double post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937774/table-cell-width-issue

Comment: Well lets say you add a new row and you give that row rowspan="2" it will be twice the width a single row is if you would make it 3 it would be three times the size. But i think googling it might work better then my explanation

Comment: @Mythje I think you're confusing rowspan and colspan :)

Comment: @roryf Ow lol yea good pointing that out thanks ^^ my bad

Comment: Tables are designed for expressing tabular data … not bar charts.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As far as i know that is impossible and that makes sense since what you are trying to do is against the idea of tabular data presentation. You could however put the data in multiple tables and remove any padding and margins in between them to achieve the same result, at least visibly. Something along the lines of:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .mytable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .mytable-head {
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .mytable-head td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .mytable-body {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .mytable-body td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
    }
    .mytable-footer {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    .mytable-footer td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="mytable mytable-head">
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">25</td>
      <td width="50%">50</td>
      <td width="25%">25</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable mytable-body">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%">50</td>
      <td width="30%">30</td>
      <td width="20%">20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable mytable-body">
    <tr>
      <td width="16%">16</td>
      <td width="68%">68</td>
      <td width="16%">16</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable mytable-footer">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%">20</td>
      <td width="30%">30</td>
      <td width="50%">50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vxbk81h/)

I don't know your requirements but i'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: This is the only solution that works and is a reasonable (minimally hacky) approach

Answer (score 48):

One solution would be to divide your table into 20 columns of 5% width each, then use colspan on each real column to get the desired width, like this:

```html
<html>
<body bgcolor="#14B3D9">
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
        <col width="5%"><col width="5%">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5>25</td>
        <td colspan=10>50</td>
        <td colspan=5>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=10>50</td>
        <td colspan=6>30</td>
        <td colspan=4>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z57ehhje/)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should use colgroup. I'll update the answer with that, thanks. The reason I used 20 columns was because I imagined he might need another configuration of columns, not just the 25-50-25 and 50-30-20 he uses now, and I found the 20-column example a bit easier to understand, although indeed messier.

Comment: IMO this is a pretty ugly solution.

Comment: How is the 25-50-25 column reflecting 25% 50% and 25%? The two 25% tds are the same size, if not bigger, than the 50%. Isn't this not the solution?

Answer (score 13):

You can't have cells of arbitrarily different widths, this is generally a standard behaviour of tables from any space, e.g. Excel, otherwise it's no longer a table but just a list of text.

You can however have cells span multiple columns, such as:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">75</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As an aside, you should avoid using style attributes like `border` and `bgcolor` and prefer CSS for those.

Comment: I am coding an html email, hence i prefer to use inline styles

Comment: @user544079 ah, makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

with 5 columns and `colspan`, this is possible ([click here](http://jsfiddle.net/6pf32/)) (but doesn't make much sense to me):

```
<table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="25%">
        <col width="25%">
        <col width="25%">
        <col width="5%">
        <col width="20%">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td colspan="2">50</td>
        <td colspan="2">25</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">50</td>
        <td colspan="2">30</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```