# Different td widths in different rows in tables?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Quick-Question: how can this be achieved? (see image below)

[image: crazytable]

Setting `td` width booth in plain html and with css had no effect.

The `td` width CAN vary but only with the same width for each row.

Comment: Obligatory comment: If you need this sort of layout, it's probably not data that needs to be in a table, but should rather use div's.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Table is for tabular data, and I imagine it'd be hard to read tabular data in a table that looks like that. Might I suggest you look into some other elements? `<span>`s, maybe?

Comment: Needed for styling a very big form.

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use three separate `<table>` blocks, each with a single row having three columns of varying widths.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe it can in one table easily.

Instead, you have to use the colspan attribute to overlap cells on different rows.

For example, use 6 columns, the first row will have colspan = 2 , td, colspan = 2

The second row will have td, td colspan=2, td and so on.

It's quite messy - you might want to consider displaying your data in a different way, for example, using DIVs

Comment: Using divs was my first thought but i need this table for styling a giant form, using divs would be even as messy as using the monstreus code above.

Answer (score 6):

It's a lot to look at, but you need a parent table with three rows where each row contains another table with three columns:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Set Width of Individual Cells Here -->
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Set Width of Individual Cells Here -->
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Set Width of Individual Cells Here -->
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle to illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/2ZuW3/).

Answer (score 2):

take 1 main table with 3 tr and in each tr take another sub table with 3 column than apply css

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible without this sub-tabling. I'm having this as a bug in my layout now. Just try playing around with paddings and margins inside cells :(

"Bug" works consistently across multiple browsers.

Edit:
Hunted that one.

```
td { display: block; }
```

Don't do it at home.

Comment: This answer could use some serious clarification.  are you saying that display:block solved your problem? What does hunted that one mean? More clear, less clever please.