# HTML/CSS table display problems

Tags: html, css

I'm messing around with the aesthetics of a site I'm building and have been left scratching my head on something that looks like it should be simple, or so I thought.
I am using a table to place the content of my the site into, and when I run it through my local host (Using XAMP) the scale of table `<td>` tags is how I want it, but when I host it through my godaddy account the `<td>`s in my main content `<tr>` are scaled differently (seems to be influenced by the header row).

Here's the link to my current page and you'll see the problem. (BTW the site is not finished so any spelling mistakes and stuff like that feel free to ignore :))

http://www.sittingducksfc.co.uk/

So how would I go about creating evenly sized `<td>`'s within that row? as you can see the furthest right `<td>` is squashed to the same scale as the loginbox at the top. I have been fiddling with it for a while but I'm probably missing some simple css but I haven't found any previous question with the same problem.

Regards
Mike

Comment: For me your site looks fine.which part is actually messing up?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, underneath the navigation section the 3 td's that are side by side are uneven and the right one has been squashed to a small scale compared to the others. id be interested to know what browser your using?

Comment: You could do with `table-layout:fixed`. And a DOCTYPE. But why are you using a table anyway? Tables are geared towards displaying grid-like data, not newspaper-like columns.

Comment: to be honest the look of it is what i wanted, im more used to swing/awt in java so i wasn't sure how to get that look using anything else. Is there a flexible table layout like gridbag in java in can use? oh and i will use DOCTYPE i just haven't got round to do my snag list yet but that's definitely on it. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all thanks for your responses.

From trail and error i have gone for a different approach and stacked multiple tables into my main div and that allows me to specify the particular widths of each td within that particular table.

From further investigation it can also be seen
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows) and i apologize for a repeat question.

Here is my example code.

```
<div>
<table width="100%"  height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td width="80%"></td>
<td width="20%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="100%"  height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td width="33%"></td>
<td width="34%"></td>
<td width="33%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This can be stacked many times without each table affecting the other.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem appears to by your stylesheet... You have the three `<td>` which all have the width of 33%

I am using **Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63m** and it shows up fine but other browsers may not, i would suggest to do the following change

`<td colspan="1" style="background-color:white;text-align:center;width: 30%;height:30%;">`

I would also suggest using a stylesheet as opposed to editing the style in-line

Comment: Hey mate thanks for your answer but it has no affect on it either. looks the same. Is it that its inheriting its dimension from the header row? i was only using the style tags so i can make quick changes to the look without having to switch class. and will be using a css when its fixed.

Comment: @mike what browser are you using?