# Table with fixed layout 100% width cannot have unequal column widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table set to 100% width whose columns I would like to acquire defined widths. However, all my columns seem to get equal widths.

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table th[colspan=4] {
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  text-align: center;
}

.table td.one {
  width: 10%;
}

.table td.two {
  width: 20%;
}

.table td.three {
  width: 50%;
}

.table td.four {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">All Four</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">All Four</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">A</td>
      <td class="two">B</td>
      <td class="three">C</td>
      <td class="four">D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If I remove the width property on the table, it honours the individual column widths. If I change the layout to `table-layout: auto`, then also it works. But I just cannot get the widths to be what I want them to be if I have a row that spans multiple columns as the first row.

Comment: this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows

Comment: No it's not that. I am not after having different widths for different rows. It's about coexisting colspan and unique widths in a 100% width table with fixed layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I remove the width property on the table, it honours the individual
>   column widths. If I change the layout to table-layout: auto, then also
>   it works. But I just cannot get the widths to be what I want them to
>   be if I have a row that spans multiple columns as the first row

That is how the `table-layout: fixed` works.

From here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

And from here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

> In this manner, the user agent can begin to lay out the table once the
>   entire first row has been received. Cells in subsequent rows do not
>   affect column widths.

So, in effect:

1. If you change the layout to `auto`, it will use the automatic table layout and your column widths take precedence over the content size.
2. If you remove the `width` property on a table, then it ceases to use the fixed table layout and is as good as `auto`.

The other answer works because the `width` property is removed (*just as you mentioned in your question*). If you refer back to the specs linked above, it says:

> The table's width may be specified explicitly with the 'width'
>   property. A value of 'auto' (for both 'display: table' and 'display:
>   inline-table') means use the automatic table layout algorithm.

**Solution**:

The solution to your problem is to somehow get the table layout to ignore the first row. This is done by the `colgroup` / `col` elements. Remove the classes which define the widths on the `td`, and specify those on the `cols`.

**Snippet**:

```css
.table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
.table td, th {
  border: 1px solid #aaa; 
  text-align: center; padding: 4px;
}
.table col.one { width: 10%; }
.table col.two { width: 20%; }
.table col.three { width: 50%; }
.table col.four { width: 20%; }
```

```html
<table class="table">
 <colgroup>
  <col class="one"/>
  <col class="two"/>
  <col class="three"/>
  <col class="four"/>
 </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th colspan="4">All Four</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="4">All Four</th></tr>
    <tr>
      <td >A</td>
      <td >B</td>
      <td >C</td>
      <td >D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Really nice answer with detailed information and doku links, thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I like the colgroup approach - keeps the table more semantic

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, I can't exactly you tell you "why". But if you change the `width: 100%;` to `min-width: 100%` you get the desired result. I guess it's because if you set the width to 100%, the overall width of each column can not be calculated.

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.table th[colspan=4] {
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  text-align: center;
}

.table td.one {
  width: 10%;
}

.table td.two {
  width: 20%;
}

.table td.three {
  width: 50%;
}

.table td.four {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">All Four</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">All Four</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">A</td>
      <td class="two">B</td>
      <td class="three">C</td>
      <td class="four">D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The Op mentioned that they already know this -- "*[..]If I remove the width property on the table, it honours the individual column widths[]..*"

Comment: @Abhitalks that is correct. But it seems OP wanted a width of 100% and happen to struggle with an alternative way of declaration. Hence this should be the desired solution imho.

Comment: Ahh.. ok, fair enough Nico. Thanks. I thought, you missed that. Deleting my comment in 5 secs.

Comment: @Abhitalks no harm was done. You can let your comment there, since your point is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had gone with your answer until @Abhitalks nailed it :-)

Comment: @adarshr thank you for your feedback. You made the right choice. My answer is not as complete as the provided and rightfully accepted one