# Do not scale other columns when one gets larger

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table and this table has 4 rows and two columns, when the second row has more words, the current column scales forward leaving the other rows with spaces.

I left the code here:

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td>name<td><td>cat</td></tr>
<tr><td>pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis<td><td>vulcano</td></tr>
<tr><td>age<td><td>2 years</td></tr>
<tr><td>sex<td><td>male</td></tr>
</table>
```

I wanted each row to remain with its column intact, for example:

```
[name: | cat]

[pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis: | vulcano]

[age: | 2 years]

[sex: | male]
```

The code is leaving like this:

```
[name:                                          | cat]

[pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis: | vulcano]

[age:                                           | 2 years]

[sex:                                           | male]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: then you should not use a table

Comment: Not possible with a `table`.

Comment: Got it, I thought I had some way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question here:
[html table cell width for different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows)

The sum of the answer: 
You can't using this method -- Table structure doesn't work that way.

You have a couple options:

1. Put each row in it's own table:

   ```
   <table border="1">
     <tr><td>name<td><td>cat</td></tr>
   </table>
   <table border="1">
     <tr><td>pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis<td><td>vulcano</td></tr>
   </table>
   <table border="1">
     <tr><td>age<td><td>2 years</td></tr>
   </table>
   <table border="1">
     <tr><td>sex<td><td>male</td></tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. Use the div element and CSS instead of tables.

Comment: Helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can close the td tag in each data
Eg :namecat
       age2 years
Like this.               ^^^

Comment: could you give an example?