# How to force html to give the width of a column you want?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project where I need to coloring columns of an html table based on how much percentage of a total that data takes up. For example if Alice has 3 apples and 1 orange, that row should be 75% colored for apple, and the other 25% for orange. And if Bob has 2 apples and 2 oranges is should be colored 50/50. My expertise isn't in HTML/CSS, so I am very confused with how my html is working.
If do only one row of a table I get the correct answer, but when I add rows, they couple together and don't have the same proportions.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
  <td width="10%" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="80%" bgcolor="#304aa6">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="10%" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="6%" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="16%"bgcolor="#304aa6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="76" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Am I doing something wrong, and is there a way I can fix it?
Thanks

[Coupled Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxVhg.png)

Comment: refer this link you will get a answer <br< https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution out:

```
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .mytable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .mytable-head {
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .mytable-head td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .mytable-body {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .mytable-body td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
    }
    .mytable-footer {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    .mytable-footer td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="mytable mytable-head">
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">25</td>
      <td width="50%">50</td>
      <td width="25%">25</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable mytable-body">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%">50</td>
      <td width="30%">30</td>
      <td width="20%">20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable mytable-body">
    <tr>
      <td width="16%">16</td>
      <td width="68%">68</td>
      <td width="16%">16</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="mytable mytable-footer">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%">20</td>
      <td width="30%">30</td>
      <td width="50%">50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Credits to @TokPhobia for this answer ([html table cell width for different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows))

Answer (score 0):

tables have columns. The width of a column is constant.  Use separate tables

```css
table{
box-sizing:unset;
border-spacing:0;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
  <td width="10%" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="80%" bgcolor="#304aa6">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="10%" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
 <td width="6%" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="16%"bgcolor="#304aa6">&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="76%" bgcolor="#4a5666">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're printing two rows of table in a wrong way, try to use col and row class in your tag. That's how it'll be responsive also won't need to add the width too.