# How to make this layout by display:table

Tags: html, css

Just started to learn CSS and happened to see some discussion about  `display:table` for web layout. I made a [simple pen](https://codepen.io/shawnchen1980/pen/apoXKb) in which a two-row layout is created by inline-block and floats respectively. I doubt if `display:table` can be used to do this.

```css
    .container{
       width:500px;
       height:200px;
       border:1px solid green;
       margin:10px;
    }

    .a, .b {
       display:inline-block;
       background:grey;
       border:1px solid red;
       box-sizing:border-box;
       vertical-align:top;
     }

    .a {
       width:30%;
       height:50%;
     }

     .b {
       width:70%;
       height:50%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="a">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can be done, with additional HTML (one wrapper div for/per two blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such layouts it is best to avoid `display: table` as your cells vary in size in per column.

For layouts such as these, your best bet is to use `display: flex` which is very versatile and allows a greater amount of flexibility than `inline-block` and  `float`.
One downside of this is that it may not be compatible with older browsers, check the [compatibility list here](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex)

Here is a great place to [get started with flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

p.s. if you really want to go through with `display: table` you could try the answers suggested in the below SO question: 
[table cell width issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937774/table-cell-width-issue)

Answer (score 0):

can use `display: flex`, it's now the best solution.